# Telescope app - "Exited with code : 8" error and app crashing

Tags: meteor, telescope

I'm new to meteor and playing with Telescope for past few days. Yesterday, I updated the Packages. From then on I'm not able to run the Telescope app in my Mac.

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
I20151128-19:27:24.429(8)? Kadira: completed instrumenting the app
W20151128-19:27:24.432(8)? (STDERR) 
W20151128-19:27:24.432(8)? (STDERR) /Users/bala/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.jru118++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151128-19:27:24.432(8)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20151128-19:27:24.433(8)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20151128-19:27:24.433(8)? (STDERR) Error: deny: Value for `update` must be a function
W20151128-19:27:24.433(8)? (STDERR)     at packages/mongo/collection.js:755:1
W20151128-19:27:24.433(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (packages/es5-shim/.npm/package/node_modules/es5-shim/es5-shim.js:417:1)
W20151128-19:27:24.433(8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105:1)
W20151128-19:27:24.433(8)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].addValidator (packages/mongo/collection.js:752:1)
W20151128-19:27:24.433(8)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.deny (packages/mongo/collection.js:804:1)
W20151128-19:27:24.433(8)? (STDERR)     at Posts.getNotificationProperties.properties.postAuthorName (lib/herald.js:7:21)
W20151128-19:27:24.433(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/bala/meteor/Telescope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:249:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Can anyone pls help me on this.

*Herald.js file is below

```
if (Meteor.absoluteUrl().indexOf('localhost') !== -1) 

Herald.settings.queueTimer = 1000; 
Meteor.startup(function () { 

Herald.collection.deny({ update: !Users.can.editById, remove: !Users.can.editById }); 

// disable all email notifications when "emailNotifications" is set to false 

Herald.settings.overrides.email = !Settings.get('emailNotifications', true); });
```

Comment: tried updating meteor? might be some compatibility issue.

Comment: Yes I tried updating Meteor as well. Still the same issue

Comment: Can you paste lib/herald.js file here? please update the question with the code.

Comment: if (Meteor.absoluteUrl().indexOf('localhost') !== -1)
  Herald.settings.queueTimer = 1000;

Meteor.startup(function () {

  Herald.collection.deny({
    update: !Users.can.editById,
    remove: !Users.can.editById
  });

  // disable all email notifications when "emailNotifications" is set to false
  Herald.settings.overrides.email = !Settings.get('emailNotifications', true);

});

Comment: code in comments is not readable. Please update the question if you really wants somebody to check it.

Comment: updated the question with herald.js file. Can you have a look?

Comment: where is this line: Posts.getNotificationProperties.properties.postAuthorName ?

Comment: This line is not present in the source herald.js

Comment: the error is inside deny function.

Comment: Please add Posts.getNotificationProperties.properties.postAuthorName.deny function

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the recent Meteor 1.2 update. I would start by making sure you're using the latest version of all Telescope packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have'd similar error with my meteor app, solved like this:
Close browser, exit terminal, reboot, open terminal, start app. It's something with browser.